# Calculate the Topographic Ruggedness Index using GDAL

Tags: gdal, anaconda

I have never used GDAL and I need to calculate the TRI. I have the DEM input I just do not know any of the code in anaconda.

How can I calculate the Topographic Ruggedness Index using GDAL?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you have then never read the documentation of gdaldem either https://gdal.org/programs/gdaldem.html.

> Generate a Terrain Ruggedness Index (TRI) map from any GDAL-supported
> elevation raster:
>
> gdaldem TRI input_dem output_TRI_map
> [-alg Wilson|Riley]
> [-compute_edges] [-b Band (default=1)] [-of format] [-q]